# Unity WebGL System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes not working with blob URL

Tags: unity-webgl

I have a problem with this code:

```
byte[] dataToPost = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

When I use the filePath of an image in Application.persistentDataPath everything works fine.

But I am not able to use a blob URL like this for filePath:
"blob:http://localhost:8000/3dcf66b0-5052-4b2d-bc00-070255483b48"

It gives me following error:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/blob:http:/localhost:8000/3dcf66b0-5052-4b2d-bc00-070255483b48".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

**In the error message it seems it messes up the blob URL to:
"/blob:http:/localhost:8000/3dcf66b0-5052-4b2d-bc00-070255483b48"**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the byte array with System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes I use now following coroutine provided by sumpfkraut:

```
//Load the byte[] from blob or from url.
    private IEnumerator LoadFile(string url)
    {
        using UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        if (uwr.error != null) Debug.Log(uwr.error);
        else
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[uwr.downloadHandler.data.Length];
            System.Array.Copy(uwr.downloadHandler.data, 0, result, 0, uwr.downloadHandler.data.Length);
            Debug.Log("Loaded file size: " + uwr.downloadHandler.data.Length + " bytes");
            //Do something with the byte array now...
            ByteResultExamples(result);
        }
    }
```